# How can i use external thermometers with vb.net

Tags: windows, interface

i am a programmer, i primarily use asp.net to write web apps. I have a need to use some external temperate sensors and a controller to run a solar water heater. I will need to be able to monitor more than one temperature sensor and start/stop a water pump based on certain logic. I can code this but my question is where do i find such equipment i.e. what can i search for etc. and how can i get it to interface so i can use it in programming.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at netduino and the micro framework. This article seems to cover what you want http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/08/02/temperature-monitoring-using-vb-net-and-the-micro-framework-and-a-netduino.aspx

Comment: http://www.sparkfun.com/ <-- also carries external sensors of various kinds (including temp) as well as programming instructions for most.